# 400 Recipient address required, when I called the API gmail with curl

Tags: api, curl, gmail-api

I want to use :

> curl --request POST \
> 'https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]'
> \   --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \   --header
> 'Accept: application/json' \   --header 'Content-Type:
> application/json' \   --data
> '{"raw":"","payload":{"partId":"","headers":[{"name":"MIME-Version","value":"1.0"},{"name":"Subject","value":"Subject
> test"},{"name":"From","value":"email1@gmail.com"},{"name":"To","value":"email2@gmail.com,
> email3@gmail.com"}]}}' \   --compressed

But I always have error like :

> {   "error": {
> "code": 400,
> "message": "Recipient address required",
> "errors": [
> {
> "message": "Recipient address required",
> "domain": "global",
> "reason": "invalidArgument"
> }
> ],
> "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"   } }

I use Gmail for Developers > Gmail API to test it:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/send

1. GET [https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{userId}/messages/{id}](https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/%7BuserId%7D/messages/%7Bid%7D) => work well
2. GET [https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{userId}/messages](https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/%7BuserId%7D/messages) => work well
3. POST [https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{userId}/messages/send](https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/%7BuserId%7D/messages/send) => **KO**

Do you have any idea why this error?

Comment: Could you share the sample code you are using to send the email? It could be that you are not using the [rfc822 format](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc822/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had to base64 encode the raw content of the email so it allows to send the email. You can use this [online encoder](https://www.base64encode.org/) to generate the email and then encode it and submit it to the raw parameter, the parameters in your example should be like:

```
From: test@gmail.com,
To: test2@gmail.com,
Subject:Gmail API test
Content-type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1,

This is a test.
```

Once encoded you just need to add the result in the raw parameter like:

```
curl --request POST \
  'https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"raw":"RnJvbTogdGVzdEBnbWFpbC5jb20sCiAgICBUbzogdGVzdDJAZ21haWwuY29tLAogICAgU3ViamVjdDpHbWFpbCBBUEkgdGVzdAogICAgQ29udGVudC10eXBlOiB0ZXh0L2h0bWw7Y2hhcnNldD1pc28tODg1OS0xLAoKICAgIFRoaXMgaXMgYSB0ZXN0IHBsZWFzZSB3b3JrLg=="}' \
  --compressed
```

Then it will result in the email being sent.